# AWS loadbalancer for same ec2 for diffrent ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have some ec2 machine that run the same code on different ports.
I want to use the aws loadbalancer to route the requests to different ports every time.
for example:

post to port 80 will send to port 4000
post to port 80 will send to port 4001
post to port 80 will send to port 4002

Can i do it?

Thank You

Comment: No, its not possible.

Comment: @Marcin I can't use target group for each port?

Comment: You can use TGs, but ALB will not randomly choose ports. The client has to choose which port to use.